# Find the column/field in error

Tags: db2, cobol, mainframe

I am working on a mainframe and my DB2 Cobol program got abended with SQLCODE -407 while inserting a row in a table. I know the remedy to this error, but the INSERT query is inserting into more than 100 fields. Is there any other way other than putting displays to know which field is in error for the NULL values. Below is the error message I received:

```
DB2ERRD  **ERROR** DB2 CALL UNSUCCESSFUL.  SQLCODE = -407.  WARNING FLAGS =     
 DSNT408I SQLCODE = -407, ERROR:  AN UPDATE, INSERT, OR SET VALUE IS NULL, BUT THE OBJECT COLUMN  CANNOT CONTAIN NULL 
          VALUES                                                                
 DSNT418I SQLSTATE   = 23502 SQLSTATE RETURN CODE                               
 DSNT415I SQLERRP    = DSNXRIHB SQL PROCEDURE DETECTING ERROR                   
 DSNT416I SQLERRD    = -136  0  0  -1  0  0 SQL DIAGNOSTIC INFORMATION          
 DSNT416I SQLERRD    = X'FFFFFF78'  X'00000000'  X'00000000'  X'FFFFFFFF'  X'00000000'  X'00000000' SQL DIAGNOSTIC 
      INFORMATION
```

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that you have `INSERT INTO SomeTable(Col1, Col2, …, Col100) VALUES(:var1, :var2, …, :var100)` or something similar (where the `:varN` notation is either a variable reference or a literal value.  My guess would be the table has an extra column, Col101, that has the NOT NULL attribute and no default specified.  This would end up attempting to insert a NULL into that column, and the attempt would be rejected. IOW: your program may be OK except that the schema of the table it is working against has changed.  Debugging: look hard at the actual schema of the table and your code.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would expect the name of your column in error to show up in your `SQLCODE` message (and indeed, it appears as if there are two spaces between `COLUMN` and `CANNOT`, where I would expect the column name to be).

However, according to [the docs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n407.dita), the actual column name may also show up in the [`SQLCA`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_descriptionofsqlcafields.dita). I would try outputting the values of `SQLERRMC` to see if your column shows up in there.